# fetching from core data

Tags: core-data

I am trying to write a fetch routine for data from Core Data. I have managed to fetch all the data in the database and display this in a table view but, how do you fetch only some of the data based on a query?

for example, in SQL:

```
Select * from DB where name = 'bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to use NSPredicate for that. something along these lines

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name == %@)", name];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```